# Hash with md5 in loop with Python

Tags: python, hash, md5

I try to find the md5 hash of an input starting with 5 '0'

```
import md5
my_input = raw_input()
it = 1 
good_start = False

while not good_start:
    m = md5.new()
    m.update(my_input+str(it))
    my_string = m.hexdigest()
    good_start = my_string[0:4].count('0') == 5
    it += 1
    if it==609043:
        print my_string
        break
```

Here is the expected output

```
000001dbbfa3a5c83a2d506429c7b00e
```

Here is the ouput I get

```
48fbdf1af6eb206e65ef98bf8a78ad85
```

Comment: Are you missing the bit of your example code where you increment `it`?

Comment: Can you make this very simple? Instead of the indirect results which require us to deduce what values were in play, simply `print` the value that's going to be hashed and the value it hashes to. If you still get differing results with the same input to `m.update`, let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're incrementing `it` *before* doing the comparison:

```
 it += 1
 if it==609043:
   print my_string
```

this means you'll see the value of `my_string` for when `it` was 609042